# How might I convert a Rectangle to a RectangleF?

Tags: .net, graphics, gdi+

What is the easiest way to convert a `Rectangle` to a `RectangleF` in .NET?

**Edit:** This sounds trivial and it is, but I was trying to save some typing. The best I could come up with:

```
RectangleF rdest(rsrc.Location, rsrc.Size); // C++/CLI
```

...or...

```
RectangleF rdest = new RectangleF(rsrc.Location, rsrc.Size) // C#
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's an implicit converter, so you can simply do:

```
RectangleF rectanglef = rectangle;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectanglef.op_implicit.aspx

In fact, you already knew that: it's easily missed, but your code is using two such implicit casts - you're using `Point` and `Size` where there should be `PointF` and `SizeF`.

Comment: The OP *implicitly* knows it ;)